# How to save plots from multiple python scripts using an interactive C# process command?

Tags: c#, python, plot, command-line, python.net

I've been trying to save plots(multiple) from different scripts using an interactive C# process command.

**Objective:** My aim is to save plots by executing multiple scripts in a single interactive python shell and that too from C#.

Here's the code which I've tried from my end.

**Code snippet:**

```
class Program
{
    static string data = string.Empty;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process pythonProcess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + "python.exe -i");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\python";
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pythonProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
        pythonProcess.ErrorDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;
        pythonProcess.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
        pythonProcess.Start();
        pythonProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        pythonProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        while (data != string.Empty)
        {
            if (data == "Type \"help\", \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.")
            {
                pythonProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("execfile('script1.py')");
                pythonProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("execfile('script2.py')");
                break;
            }
        }
        pythonProcess.WaitForExit();
    }

    private static void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        data = e.Data;
    }

    private static void Process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        data = e.Data;
    }
}
```

**Scripts:**

*script1.py*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('script1.png')
```

*script2.py*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.savefig('script2.png')
```

From the above C# code, you could see that I've tried to execute both the scripts. But, during the execution, the plot from the first script (*script1.py*) alone gets saved, whereas the second one (*script2.py*) doesn't.

All I need to know is, how come the second script plot doesn't gets saved and what's the reason behind this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try introducing a StreamWriter.Flush() after                 
`pythonProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("execfile('script1.py')");`
or setting the 
`StreamWriter.AutoFlush  = true`

Alternatively either use a  separate thread for each script / chain the execution of the scripts using Task Parallel Library

Comment: @Ramkumar why not use pythonnet?! it is compatible with both numpy and matplotlib. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Answer (score 1):

Since you are opening a python shell and then sending it the commands:

```
execfile('script1.py')
execfile('script2.py')
```

Immediately one after the other I suspect that the second command is being sent during time taken to load `numpy` and `matplotlib` - you need to check the output from the first `execfile` to make sure that it has **finished** before issuing the second, or you need to use a different thread for each - at the moment you have a single thread attempting to perform two separate actions almost at once.

Note that once you have finished with your python shell it is a **very** good idea to exit it by sending `exit()` to the process stdin and calling `process.WaitForExit()`.

Also note that using a shell to call python code and execute external threads is classed as a security vulnerability in addition to being slow, reliant on the user having python installed, etc., you might be better off looking at using [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) - but the only actively maintained plotting library that ***I*** was able to find is the *non-free* [ILNumerics Visualization Engine](http://ilnumerics.net/visualization-engine.html).

Comment: Does IronPython support numpy and matplotlib now?

Comment: @denfromufa - AFAIK there are a couple of projects ongoing for matplotlib but numpy is now available for IronPython.

Comment: do you have any links?

Comment: @denfromufa numpy: http://blog.enthought.com/python/scipy-for-net/#.V9zTwpgrKUk & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412412/ironpython-libraries-for-scientific-plots has some possibilities.

Comment: "now available" is 5 year old fork of numpy and cython, not supported for 5 years. Not even binaries are available.